# how to update information in the app

Tags: sql-update, xcode5

I am totally beginner for iOS developing. I am planning to make a menu app. The problem I am encountering is I can get three weeks menu at once, after three weeks I have to update the menu for users. But how can I make it ? 
Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would do this is to pull the menu from an API using either JSON or XML and save it in local sqlite db that you create in document folder the first time your application launches. And then populate your presentation layer from sqlite.